# Error 102 when connect to FB API

Tags: php, facebook

I am seeing this error message when I connect to fb

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: 
parameters uid or session key required thrown in C:\Online\lib\fb\base_facebook.php
on line 708
```

May I know what is the problem? I have verified the appID and Secret Key too. Thank you.

Here is my code in php

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => FB_ID, 'secret' => FB_SCRT, 'cookie' => true,)); 
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        $api_call = array(
            'method' => 'users.hasAppPermission',
            'uid' => $user,
            'ext_perm' => 'publish_stream'
        );
        $users_hasapppermission = $facebook->api($api_call);
```

I am trying to have the user's permission to publish to FB stream

Comment: will you explain what exactly you are trying to do? by which way you trying to connect?